# Как отменить наследуемость?

Tags: html, css

```css
a {
background-color: red;
opacity: 0.1;
}

span {
  font-size: 30px;
  color: #000000;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <a>
    <span>текст</span>
  </a>
</div>
```

Могу ли я каким то способом отменить opacity для span не переписывая код?

Comment: добавить в span свой opacity с нужным значением. как вариант

Comment: Вот так просто - никак. В зависимости от особенностей вашей реализации навскидку вижу два варианта: 1) сделать прозрачным фон (если прозрачность только ради него делается) через `rgba`; 2) вынести текст за пределы прозрачной ссылки, наложив его сверху через `position:absolute`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Прозрачный фон нужно делать через альфа-канал:

```css
a {
  background: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

span {
  font-size: 30px;
  color: #000000;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <a>
    <span>текст</span>
  </a>
</div>
```